# Making a select with an array

Tags: sql, typescript

Hello I have and Array with objects, each object have atributes that I need for an select:

In this case it is the result from another consult with typeorm
" const CompaniesRelation: Array = await getRepository(CompanyRelation).find({ where:{ UserId: data.UserId, IsActive: true} });"

```
Companies: Array = [{CompanyId="a"}{CompanyId="b"}{CompanyId="c"}];
```

I need to make an select of all the data that matches with the Ids that are into Companies so for that I need to make an SQL like it:

```
const CompanyData: Array = SELECT * 
FROM Company 
INNER JOIN Company.CompanyId = CompaniesRelation[].CompanyId;
```

but it throw me error in typing, ¿how can I acces to each objetc into the array for make that match?

At the final I should traduce it sql to typeOrm, but I new and solving first in SQL it should help me to traduce to typeorm

Comment: Hi, are you trying to query from DB, company rows using the array you have defined?

Comment: Also, are you using typescript. If so, please ensure your code is syntactically correct...

Comment: @AshwynHorton Yes I'm trying to do that, and yes I'm using typescrypt, let me edit

Comment: @AshwynHorton I added some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay great, let us consider what we have to work with right:

So first we have a statement that gets a list of companies like so:

```
const CompaniesRelation: Array = await getRepository(CompanyRelation).find({
  where: {
    UserId: data.UserId,
    IsActive: true
  }
});
```

which ends up with something like this:

```
[ { CompanyId: 'a' }, { CompanyId: 'b' }, { CompanyId: 'c' } ]
```

Now we want to get a list of companies from an SQL DB with these Company IDs.

So the query should look like this:

```
// so first we re map the relation to an array of strings...
const ids: Array<string> = CompaniesRelation.map(c => c.CompanyId);

// then use it in the query, note the string interpolation for the query
const query: string = `SELECT * FROM Company WHERE CompanyId IN(${JSON.stringify(ids).slice(1, -1)});`;
```

I don't think this will cover the scope of the problem you have, I hope it helps though...feel free to ask

Comment: I think that works, actually you simplify for me the next step(change it for typeorm),the sintaxys of orm is a little confusing for me when is about joins. So only for have more clear the topic, this sql could work like the same way?
SELECT * FROM Company INNER JOIN Company.CompanyId = CompanyRelation.CompanyId INNER JOIN CompanyRelation.UserID = 'UserId'